# power law distribution fitting

Tags: r, power-law

I have a sample of data, with the sample size being around 500,000. I am currently trying to fit the sample with power law distribution, using the `poweRlaw` package in R.

So this is my code to that end:

```
pl_rg <- conpl$new(a)
estimate_xmin(pl_rg, xmax = 100)
```

However, there comes the problem when I try to run the code of `x<-estimate_xmin(pl_rg,xmax = 100)`. I found this code was very very time consuming. I have run this code by now for up to 5 hours and it is still running.

So any way to accelerate the process or other ways to fit the power law?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and for questions wherein you have working code that you'd like to speed up please consider moving your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `estimate_xmin` is slow is that it is trying every possible value of your data for a potential `xmin` value. You can significantly speed up the function by specifying values, e.g.

```
estimate_xmin(pl_rg, xmins = 1:10)
```

See the help page for further details.

Comment: Thanks. but how can I specify the initial values for xmin ? Can  I just choose several values according to the probability density function of the data as where the plot starts to be linear in the log-log axis?

Comment: In the code above you are choosing xmin values using the `xmins` argument.